# What will ls -l | wc -l command display?

Tags: ls, wc

Will:

```
ls -l|wc -l
```

Display the number of devices too? (Including files and directories)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will show the number of lines output by `ls -l` which will include everything that has an entry in the current directory, including files (including special files if present), links, and directories.

Answer (score 3):

No `ls -l | wc -l` will report the number of lines the `ls -l` command would give.  Roughly the number of files+directories in the current directory plus something for the header.

Comment: If you're in `/dev` it'd give some sense of the number of devices, or potential ones since most of those get character special or block special files.  So it may well show a potential number of devices/partitions/etc. beyond standard files

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and also symlinks and sockets. And the first line (there are several questions here about what that number means) will also be counted.

But you'll typically only find devices in `/dev` (with subdirectories) and there's typically very few files there, so I'm wondering if that's really what you want to do. What are you trying to accomplish?

Also `ls` defaults to only putting one file name  on each line when output is not to a terminal, and all the extra output generated by `-l` is wasted anyway, so `ls | wc -l` will give the same.

Answer (score 1):

`ls -l` will display how many files contain the currunt directory and  in long format. in total n files +1 line for total X as header.
`| wc -l` counts the total lines that is fed so in total you will have n+1 (lines+(1)header after executing  `ls -l | wc -l`